# Multiple bar plot from dataframe after grouping by gender

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have been trying to do this efficiently for quite a lot now. I have this dataframe where in each row, there is the university programme, the gender and whether or not (or unknown) the student has taken a course. This is an example:

```
d = {'programme': ['physics', 'math', 'philosophy'],
    'course1': [1, 2, 0],
    'course2': [1, 2, 0],
    'gender': ['male', 'female', 'unknown']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like, for each course, to make a bar plot where on the x-axis there are the different master programmes and the height of the bars depend on the number of 1s (corresponding to yes) for that programme but grouped by gender.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What does a 2 for course 1 or 2 mean?  0 = "No, hasn't taken course", 1 = "Yes, has taken course", from what I understand.  Is 2 "unknown" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not specifying that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like seaborn.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

d = {'programme': ['physics', 'math', 'philosophy'],
 'course1': [1, 2, 0],'course2': [1, 2, 0],
 'gender': ['male', 'female', 'unknown']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.pivot_table(columns=['programme','gender']).T # There's probably a better way to do this.

df = df.replace([0, 2], pd.NA).groupby(['programme', 'gender']).count()
df['counts'] = df.sum(axis=1)

sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='programme', y='counts', hue='gender')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]